# li :hover background effect goes behind the parent container's background

Tags: css, html-lists, background-image, css-transitions, z-index

I'm trying to achieve this
[social icons hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFYYU.png)

The dark background should moves down and fill the box on mouse over. This works perfectly when I use no background for the parent container but the hover effect goes behind the parent container when a background image is used.

[Screenshot: not showing when bg image set for parent container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pORH3.png)

and I can see the effect when an opacity value is set for the parent container.

I've tried using negative z-index for the parent but not working for some reason.

My code

```css
.hero {
 background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-640-480-3.jpg') no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 550px;
 padding: 40px 10px;
  
    /*opacity :0.5; Works in Background*/
}
.social-icons {
  
}

.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 60px 5px 5px 60px;
  text-decoration: none;  
  position: relative; 
  border: 3px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.social-icons li:hover {
  color: #000;

}
.social-icons li:hover:before {
  left: -55px;  
}

.social-icons li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -280px;
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  transform: skew(-50deg);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
.social-icons li a {
  color: #000000;
  display:block;
}
.social-icons li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="hero">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="social-icons">
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: For future users to know, and as you are supposed to do, it would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that best helped you solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this, give the anchor `a` a position, i.e. `position: relative` and remove the `z-index`.

I also adjusted your `li:before`/`li:hover:before` rules a little, so the transition work both ways.

```css
.hero {
 background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-640-480-3.jpg') no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 550px;
 padding: 40px 10px;
    /*opacity :0.5; Works in Background*/
}
.social-icons { 
}
.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 60px 5px 5px 60px;
  position: relative; 
  border: 3px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.social-icons li:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.social-icons li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 280px;
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  transform: skew(-50deg);
  width: 250px;
  transition: left .2s linear;
}
.social-icons li:hover:before {
  left: -20px;
  transition: left .2s linear;
}
.social-icons li a {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
  display:block;
}
.social-icons li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="hero">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="social-icons">
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```